# Left join multiple tables after migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have here a stored procedure, we have migrated to SQL Server 2016 so that some command from previous version needed to update. But I am having trouble in some command as it is showing errors. Below is my sample code.

```
if @stat = '%' 
   DECLARE onground_cur CURSOR for
   SELECT pkgh_type, pkgd_date, pkgd_area, pkgd_intcost, pkgd_billcost, pkgh_advcde,
      pkgh_agencde, pkgh_refno, pkgd_ae, pkgd_currency, bs_invno, bs_exinvno, pkgd_cpno
   FROM pckg_hdr, pckg_dtl, bill_sked
   WHERE pkgh_refno = pkgd_refno
      and pkgh_type in ('C', 'X')
      and pkgd_date between @dtfrom and @dtto
      and (pkgd_stat = 'I' or pkgd_stat = 'A')
      and pkgd_area like ltrim(@s_area)
      and pkgd_currency like ltrim(@p_currency)
      and pkgh_agencde like ltrim(@s_agency)
      and pkgh_advcde like ltrim(@s_advertiser)
      and pkgh_refno *= bs_pkgrefno
      and pkgd_dtlno *= bs_pckgdtlno
```

The part I need to update is those who have "*=" sign :

```
**pkgh_refno *= bs_pkgrefno and pkgd_dtlno *= bs_pckgdtlno**
```

**What I did is :**

`**pckg_hdr left join bill_sked on pkgh_refno**`

But when I tried the other one which is `pkgd_dtlno *= bs_pckgdtlno`

I cannot execute the code anymore. Also I am having trouble with left join and right join.

```
(spd_invno *= invh_invno and invh_invtp =* ordh_conttp)
```

Answer (score 0):

`*=` is not anymore [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/outer-join-operators-and-are-not-supported-in-90-or-later-compatibility-modes?view=sql-server-2014) in today's `sql server versions`, use `left outer join` instead.

```
SELECT pkgh_type, pkgd_date, pkgd_area, pkgd_intcost, pkgd_billcost, pkgh_advcde,
      pkgh_agencde, pkgh_refno, pkgd_ae, pkgd_currency, bs_invno, bs_exinvno, pkgd_cpno
FROM pckg_hdr
left outer join pckg_dtl on pkgh_refno = bs_pkgrefno
left outer join bill_sked on pkgd_dtlno = bs_pckgdtlno
WHERE pkgh_refno = pkgd_refno
      and pkgh_type in ('C', 'X')
      and pkgd_date between @dtfrom and @dtto
      and (pkgd_stat = 'I' or pkgd_stat = 'A')
      and pkgd_area like ltrim(@s_area)
      and pkgd_currency like ltrim(@p_currency)
      and pkgh_agencde like ltrim(@s_agency)
      and pkgh_advcde like ltrim(@s_advertiser)
```